# Where are the application logs for node.js on AWS OpsWorks

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

This is probably something really easy, but I can't find the where node.js is logging on AWS OpsWorks. I ssh into an instance, I confirm node is running and listening on port 80, yet the usual /var/log/nodejs does not exist, and the log directory that seems to have been created in my application root is empty. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something I experienced recently. Monit configuration for NodeJs apps doesn't send logs to anywhere, so you can't access those logs.

> A Similar thread explains the problem and how you can fix it:
>   [Node.js OpsWorks Layer console logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183395/node-js-opsworks-layer-console-logs)

Comment: I figured out that I had to override the template, eventually, after learning how to use Chef. What a journey to simply enable logging!